# Singletons and other design issues

Tags: java, c++, actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns

I have worked using different languages like C++/Java and currently AS3. Most applications were computer vision, and small 2D computer games.  Most companies that I have worked for, they use Singletons in a language like AS3, to retrieve elements or classes in an easy way. Their problem is basically they needs some variables or to call other functions from other classes. In a language like AS3, there is no private constructor, and they write a hacky code to prevent new instances.

In Java and C++ I also faced the situation that I need to use other classe's members or to call their functions in different classes.

The question is, is there a better or another design, to let other classes interact with each others without using singletons?   I feel that composition is the answer, but I need more detailed solutions or design suggestions.

Comment: Yes... there are very many options for this, depending on what you need. The best solution is to have classes that require use of other objects to own that object (as a field), or to reference the object (non-owning). How the client class obtains their object/reference is another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Singleton pattern incorrectly conflates two issues (or perhaps I should say, most or all observed uses of it do):

- you want a global variable
- you want the restrict the number of instances of a given class in existence in the program to 1.

Mutable global state makes your program harder to reason about. But, OK, sometimes it's what you want, you can do it but don't be too proud of it. Depending on language you might need to pull some silly tricks to isolate for test purposes the units that depend on the global state.

There is pretty much no good reason ever to make the latter restriction. If you only want to use one instance of the class, fine, only create one of it. You don't have to write a special class to tell yourself to only create one of it.

So: if you want a global instance of a class create one just as you would a Singleton except don't bother trying to prevent other instances being created.

If you want every instance of the class to behave the same then consider the "Borg Pattern": write a class whose instances have no state of their own, but instead every instance operates on the global state.

*Even if* you decide that you really need a object unique of its type, you should still assess properly whether accessing it globally is appropriate, or whether it should rather be an injected dependency of those components that use it.

About the only special case I can think of is that the type of a value that has special meaning to the language could legitimately be singleton, in order to allow for special tricks in implementations. So for example `None` in Python is a singleton whose type is `NoneType`. I imagine that in all such cases the type will be immutable.

Comment: I think the main issue with singeltons is that all the examples out there in the wild are bad (or merly incomplete). The singelton pattern is not a pattern that can be used in isolation it needs to be combined with other creation patterns (to allow de-coupling of the creation of the single instance from usage (thus allowing a different single instance depending on situation (production/testing/other)). But I agree global mutable state is usually wrong.

Comment: @LokiAstari: agreed. It's not that code with Singletons in it doesn't work, it's that it restricts the ways the code can develop in future, without providing any benefit. Global mutable state in general has both a benefit and a cost, so you can at least weigh them against each other to assess a particular case.

Comment: @SteveJessop - The "Borg" pattern... is that not making the issue worse in terms of global state? Now instead of encapsulated global state (within the singleton) you have unencapsulated state. The alternative really is what you mentioned before, just build one instance of the class. The class itself does not specify its singleton-ness, the application does.

Comment: @Dennis: well, typically the global state would be somewhat encapsulated within the Borg class. I say, "*if* you want every instance to behave the same". If you don't want every instance to behave the same (and as you say that's generally not what you want) then don't use it. If you do use it, it's useful to give it a name that indicates that it's an object for prodding global state, so that the user's code reads like it's modifying mutable globals. Of course you could write a series of static functions to make the same mutations, instead of an object that access the static state.

Comment: The conflation is due to the fact that if you only want one instance, it almost has to be global.  And there are a (very) few things where you really do only want one instance: I use singletons regularly for handling command line options (there can only be one command line), the return code (again, there can only be one), and rather often for things like logging and configuration data.  (In his case, it's not clear whether he wants a singleton, or whether he's really looking for factory functions, which in C++ would be free functions.)

Comment: I think the only time I've ever actually used it was in some Symbian/C++ code implementing a games platform, where IIRC I had a Borg class for accessing a global table of plugged-in OS components. I can't remember all the details and I could probably just as well have had a function to return a reference to the table itself, but it made sense to me to have the two levels of abstraction -- the behavior of the raw table (which was not singleton although only one instance existed) vs. some operations performed on the global table.

Comment: @JamesKanze: a command-line option handler seems like an excellent case for a class that happens to only have one instance in your production code, in preference to a Singleton. That way, you can run tests which process multiple command lines and check the results, without needing to launch a process per test.

Comment: And there are a few things where it really makes sense to restrict the number of instances.  If you are modeling something like a return code, any client requesting an error return had better use the same instance which is used to get the return code before returning from `main`; the surest way to ensure this is to ensure that there can only be one instance.

Comment: Singletons are bad because they hide the code's dependencies. If you use dependency injection (just one well known solution) it's much easier to reason about.

Comment: @SteveJessop And also run the risk that options register with a different instance than the one which is passed `argc` and `argv`.  (There's also a third issue which is usually conflated with singletons in C++: order of initialization.  The `CommandLine` class must use the classical C++ singleton idiom because the `Option` are static variables, whose constructor registers with the `CommandLine`.)

Comment: @Simple: *globals* are bad for that reason. Singletons just happen to be one example of globals. And yet despite this being known for a long time, languages persist in having global namespaces, canonical names for classes by which any bit of code can just reach in and use them, etc. The reason is that global names are just so darn *convenient*, and any given program needs to strike a balance.